# Как синхронизировать клик и показ картинки?

Tags: случайные-числа, click, изображения

Дано:

1. контейнер #click, в который подгружаются внешние файлы, высота контейнера меняется
2. блок под контейнером #click - #Blot, в котором появляются рандомные картинки, когда кликают по #click.

Суть проблемы:
когда страница загрузилась, кликаем по #click и в том же месте в #Blot появляется рандомная картинка, но если проскролить - картинки начинают появляться не в месте клика, а на расстоянии.
Скриптом меняю высоту #Blot - подставляю как у #click.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как добиться синхронности по мере проскролла?

(ссылка на пример в комментарии)

Comment: Пример https://codepen.io/gargool/pen/vaXPxO

Answer (score 0):

нашел выход через css свойство **pointer-events: none;**

неправильно считались координаты клика через потомков в кликабельном слое.